# M2 SSD disk - bad sectors

Tags: lvm, disk, ssd

I have a m2 SSD disk and it has 100 bad sectors (over 3 years). Is there a risk that this type of drive will eventually break, should i do something about it or not necessarily ?

[image]

thanks

Comment: Are running fstrim? It should be logged somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, **Always have a backup**. Drive deaths can be unnatural (Your ceiling falls and crushes the drive).

Next thing is everything is perishable. It will die someday. Read the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#SSD_failure) about SSDs. SSDs die more deterministically than HDDs. HDDs are weaker than SSDs, in sense of external forces. They have moving parts which may break and the most common way they die is when their read/write head collide with the platters. But if you are lucky enough they can live decades.
SSDs are different kind of beasts, they have a limited write cycle. No SSD cell return to original state once written, gradually all cells become unwriteable.
Here is the [spec sheet](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/content/dam/toshiba-ss/asia-pacific/docs/product/storage/product-manual/SSD-SG5-Series-Brochure-Revision1.0.pdf) of your device. It says 15000 hours as Mean Time Between Failures and 5 years product life but doesn't mention what's the write limit. Also larger SSDs has longer life as they can distribute writes on more cells.

Here is the Debian wiki article on [maintenance of SSD](https://wiki.debian.org/SSDOptimization). Here is [Arch linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Solid_state_drive). And here is another U&L SE [Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243458/ssd-optimization)